# What is the difference between web3.js and ethjs?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethjs

I've seen people using both in their codes - https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js and https://github.com/ethjs.

Do I need both? Does ethjs depend on web3?

Answer (score 1):

- Web3js is an official project of the Ethereum Foundation.
- Ethjs is a lightweight reimplementation of web3.js that has an async only API. There is no dependency relationship between them.
- Another library that is widely used is [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js)

Comment: Typo in the second point? "...lightweight reimplementation of _web3.js_..."?